# Is it possible to marginalize one or several parameters obtained from fitting procedure?

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

Statistical model analysis package has a few fitting functions. Their arguments are data points, fitting model and parameters in the fit. The result is a set of best values for parameters, which represent the `"BestFit"` to the data. However, one can also specify the `ConfidenceLevel` and obtain `"ConfidenceInterval"` for every parameter, or the total `"ParameterConfidenceRegion"` for all parameters. This region will be an ***n***-dimensional ellipsoid, for the fit with ***n*** parameters.

If you are not interested in one of parameters you could marginalize it, e.g. integrate the likelihood function over all values of that parameter, ending up with ***n-1*** parameters. If you could do this for all but one parameter you would reach to the same `"ConfidenceInterval"` that Mathematica has calculated for that parameter. But if one could do this for only ***p*** parameters, one would end up with ***n-p*** parameters and the `"ParameterConfidenceRegion"` would be ***n-p*** dimensional ellipsoid.

Marginalization in terms of `"CovarianceMatrix"` is very simple - remove row and column that correspond to the parameter you want to marginalize.

Now I don't know how to get `"ParameterConfidenceRegion"` from this modified `"CovarianceMatrix"` and I don't know if Mathematica has something for parametric marginalization implemented.

Comment: Depending on your distribution you could look at the profile likelihood, that is the likelihood where you fix some prameters, the deviance statistic 2(l(best fit) - l(theta | best fit of some parameters)) which will have the chi-square(number of free parameters) distribution so you can check where the deviance statistics attains relevant quantile of the chi-square distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21417/5981) is explained how one can plot confidence region from any covariance matrix `c`. Now I am trying to figure out how to get standard equation of ellipsoid from `{x, y, z}.ci.{x, y, z} == t`, where `ci` is the inverse of `c`. This would help in analytical analysis and make the plotting easier and prettier. Position of ellipsoid is given from `Eigenvectors[c]`, but I am still missing radii. Different confidence level would influence the size of ellipsoid by scale factor `Sqrt@InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], confidenceLevel]`.